# How to hide rows from certain color to another color?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write macro to hide rows from cell with set color to cell with any other color different than white(no background color) and yellow. When I run my macro it ends row below yellow cell. Can anyone help ?
Below I upload whole module with both show and hide subs, and as far as hidegm,showgm,hidegmall,showgmall work perfectly fine the rest doesn't.

The code :

```vb
Sub showgmall()
    Dim i, v, r, w As Integer
    
    i = Worksheets(1).Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    For v = 1 To i
        If Cells(v, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(241, 228, 188) Then
            v = v + 1
            For r = v To i
                If Not Cells(r, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Or _
                           Cells(r, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next r

            r = r - 1
            w = r - v
            Rows(v).Resize(w).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next v
End Sub

Sub hidegmall()
    Dim i, v, r, z, w As Integer
    
    i = Worksheets(1).Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    For v = 1 To i
        If Cells(v, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(241, 228, 188) Then
            v = v + 1
            For r = v To i
                If Not Cells(r, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Or _
                    Cells(r, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next r
    
            r = r - 1
            w = r - v
            Rows(v).Resize(w).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next v
End Sub

Sub showms()
    Dim i, v, r, z, w As Integer
    
    i = Worksheets(1).Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    For v = 1 To i
        If Cells(v, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 249, 217) Then
            z = v + 1
            For r = z To i
                If Not Cells(r, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Or _
                       Cells(r, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next r

            r = r - 1
            w = r - z
            Rows(z).Resize(w).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next v
End Sub

Sub hidems()
    Dim i, v, r, z, w As Integer

    i = Worksheets(1).Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    For v = 1 To i
        If Cells(v, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 249, 217) Then
            z = v + 1
            For r = z To i
                If Not Cells(r, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Or _
                       Cells(r, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next r
            
            r = r - 1
            w = r - z
            Rows(z).Resize(w).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next v
End Sub
```

Comment: When posting code please try to *indent* in a meaningful way, so your code is actually easily readable.  As posted, it's difficult to follow (particularly as there's a lot of it).  You can remove the working parts if they aren't required to understand the non-working part.

Comment: Edits done, The part that isn't working properly is hidems/showms. I left the rest of the code as an example of my thinking and how should it work actually.

Comment: "any other color different than white(no background color) and yellow"  A white fill (`Interior.Color = vbWhite`) is not the same as no fill (`Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone`)  Which one do you mean here?

Comment: The color I meant here is actually no color

Comment: This sounds like poor workbook design - formatting should be used illustratively rather than to drive the logic of your VBA. If you have editorial control over the content of the workbook, consider using a conditional format, adding extra columns if needed to provide the values that'll be used in those conditions. The same values you use for your conditions can then be used in your VBA.

Comment: @jsheeran The problem with conditional formatting is that I  want to keep the excel file as intact as it can be. Also I added buttons show and hide to make it more fancy ;) .

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like the code below.  You have a lot of repeated logic which only varies in a couple of places, so make those parts parameters in a single sub and call that sub with different arguments.

Eg:

```vb
Sub ShowGmall()
    ToggleRows RGB(241, 228, 188), False
End Sub

Sub HideGmall()
    ToggleRows RGB(241, 228, 188), True
End Sub

'Show or hide rows, beginning with a cell in ColB with fill color `clr`
'  and ending with the first cell filled yellow or with no fill
'  `HideRows` = True will hide, False will unhide.
Sub ToggleRows(clr As Long, HideRows As Boolean)
    'every variable needs a type, unless you want a Variant
    Dim v As Long, c As Range, ws As Worksheet 
    
    Set ws = Worksheets(1)
    For v = 1 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        If ws.Cells(v, "B").Interior.Color = clr Then         'has the color of interest
            Set c = ws.Cells(v, "B").Offset(1)                'next cell down 
            'loop while not yellow fill and not no fill
            Do While c.Interior.Color <> vbYellow And _    
                     c.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone
                Set c = c.Offset(1, 0) 'next row              'next cell down 
            Loop
            ws.Rows(v).Resize(c.Row - v).EntireRow.Hidden = HideRows
        End If
    Next v
End Sub
```

Comment: OK, I read the code you posted earlier and think I found the issue it doesn't work as intended : the do while loop ends when cell with yellow or no fill is encountered, but it should end when any other color diffrent than both yellow or no fill is found.